# How do I get the right element with CSS selectors?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, css-selectors

I'm trying to scrape  [this page](https://www.meilleursagents.com/prix-immobilier/marseille-13000/)  to get the average price per square meter as well as the bracket. I've overcome my first obstacle (cf.  [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66729095/how-to-use-correctly-css-selectors-in-webscraping)  by using select instead of findAll) but now I can't get the wrong results. Indeed, I want to get the <ul><li> elements with my figures but I get into other <ul><li> elements (see images below).

I know that it has something to do with child nodes and the little arrows behind the <li> tag but I can't figure it out...
So what could I do to get the text "2 992 €" and the bracket text " 1962 € à 4 158 €" ???

Here is my code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

res=requests.get("https://www.meilleursagents.com/prix-immobilier/marseille-13000/")
soup=bs(res.text,"html.parser")
infos=soup.select("li",class_="big-number")
print(infos)
```

[image: what I get]
what I get (above)

[image: what I want]
what I want (above)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's looking for a valid browser ua possibly from a list specified on the server, and also there is unicode to handle

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import unicodedata
import re

headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)'}  
r = requests.get('https://www.meilleursagents.com/prix-immobilier/marseille-13000/', headers = headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "lxml")
for i in soup.select('.prices-summary__price-range'):
    print([re.sub('\n\s+', '', unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', j.text.strip())) for j in i.select('li:nth-child(n+2):nth-child(-n+3)')])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer !! I can get the right values in spite of the anti-scraping mechanism !

Answer (score 0):

Go to the dev tools, and select the element. Then click copy as css selector, and the browser automatically gives you the correct css selector. Or, you can use the xpath.

Comment: I copied as css selector the line <li class="big number"> and paste it in my code like that : `infos=soup.select("prices-summary-sell > div.prices-summary__sell-prices--container > div.prices-summary__apartment-prices > ul > li.big-number")`
However it returns an empty list (or None when using the find method)

I'm sorry @OctoppuSS7 I'm a beginner so maybe I didn't applied well your advice

Comment: If you are a beginner, this isn't the best solution, so I'd go with one of the others.

Comment: Is this possible to have the line of code then...I think I can try to figure it out
Also do you have any idea of the problem I mention in the question (with on cf.page) @OctopuSS7

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution you can give a try using the parent tag `ul` instead of `li`.

```
for ul in soup.find_all("ul", {"class": "prices-summary__price-range"}):
    for li in ul.find_all("li"):
        if li.string:
            print(li.string.strip())
```

---

```
Prix m2 moyen
2 168 €
de 
    
        1 421 €
    
 à 
    
        3 011 €

....
```

Comment: it is very weird. I copied your code and pasted it just after `soup=bs(res.text,"html.parser")` but nothing is printed...

Comment: hmm.. that is weird, just `print(res.text)` & see if the response contains the required content.

Comment: I don't think it is the print instruction the problem but rather the loops because after the if instruction I've added `print("a")` and it never prints the letter a so if is never used